# How to prevent McAfee LiveSafe from installing uTorrent on my system?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, utorrent

I used to have uTorrent installed on my laptop, but removed it using their uninstaller. Since then, uTorrent has been reappearing every so often. I started to suspect that this was somehow caused by McAfee LiveSafe.

This suspicion was confirmed when I disabled automatic updates for McAfee. Today I received the following notification:

[image]
This is in Dutch, but basically it says "We found an update for uTorrent, click here to install".

How can I stop McAfee from installing uTorrent with every new uTorrent update?

Comment: Evidently Utorrent left behind some registry entries that McAfee is picking up on.

Comment: @Moab I thought so as well but I have no clue where to find these and how to remove them.

Comment: You should be able to remove them with [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner/download)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructions below will completely eradicate all traces of uTorrent from the system.

This will solve the re-install problem.

> **Delete uTorrent registry leftovers**.
>
> Windows key + R > Type “regedit” > click OK
>
> Once you open registry editor, click File > Export to make a backup
>   first before the deletion.
>
> After you successfully back up the registry, locate the below registry
>   keys
>
> ```
>     HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -> SOFTWARE -> uTorrentControl
> ```
>
> [image: image1]
>
> ```
> HKEY_CURRENT_USER ->  Software -> BitTorrent -> uTorrent
> ```
>
> [image: image2]
>
> Right click on them and select delete.
>
> Reboot your system once more.
>
> Note: Editing registry can be dangerous, in order avoid unnecessary
>   troubles, please confirm twice about the registry keys you are about
>   to delete, and do remember to backup the registry first before any
>   operation.

**SOURCE** => [Completely Remove uTorrent From PC](http://maxuninstaller.com/howtouninstallguides/cant-uninstall-utorrent-how-to-uninstall-utorrent-completely-from-your-computer/)

---

After you do all the above, check to make sure the .exe file was deleted.

Go to => C:\Users\your_name\AppData\Roaming\utorrent

If the folder is still on your PC see if the .exe file is in the folder. If not, delete the folder.

**SOURCE** => [Locate/Remove The uTorrent.exe File](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/82678-how-do-i-completely-remove-utorrent-from-my-computer/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will test this, and if it works mark the answer as accepted. That seems like a pretty straightforward method of sorting out what's the problem :)

Comment: There was a uTorrent.exe somewhere else (appdata/local/temp), and deleting that solved the problem. Thanks for the instructions.